# Как в React рендерить компонент выше в дереве и в двух местах?

Tags: reactjs

Где-то глубоко в дереве компонентов React есть компонент `Component`, которому нужно выше в дереве (не в родительском компоненте) в компоненте `Root` отрендерить какой-то блок `Child`.

1. После размонтирования компонента `Component`, этот "дочерний" компонент `Child` (который должен находится выше в дереве в `Root`) должен размонтироваться соответственно.
2. При этом компонент `Child` может быть отрендерен в одном из компонентов `Sidebar1` или `Sidebar2`, в зависимости от каких-то условий, например, ширина экрана.
3. Таких блоков может быть очень много, поэтому нужно что бы `Component` только рисовал компонент, а `Root` уже определял логику где его рендерить: в `Sidebar1` или в `Sidebar2`.

Короче, нужно что бы компонент рендерил компонент не внутри себя, в вне себя высоко в дереве.
Как с помощью React сделать это лучше всего?

Comment: Что значит высоко в дереве? В дереве реакта или дом?

Comment: Это значит в идеале на самом высоком уровне, обычно в корневом компоненте App. В дереве компонентов React

Answer (score 0):

Так это не работает.

- Нужно [поднять состояние](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) до самого высокого компонента, допустим,
  `App`.  `App` будет пробрасывать до `Component` тригер состояния показа. `Component` переключает состояние показа. Определение что и где рендерит зависит от вашей реализации - это может определять как сам `Component`, так и хранитель состояния - `App`
- Либо запихнуть все элементы, где может быть отрендерен `Child`, в общий [контекст](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/context.html), в котором манипулировать состоянием, а также идентификатором того, где `Child` должен рендериться `{childId == this.id ? <Child /> : null}`

И в том и в ином случае сам `Component` не рендерит `Child`, он лишь отвечает за переключение показа.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вам может помочь использование порталов react
Ссылка на документацию: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)